# How do I put AppDelegate Swift code into Objective-C AppDelegate file and make it work?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, bridging-header

I'm trying to work with an Amazon Web Serivces SDK for iOS called AWSAppSync. I found [good instructions for Swift](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api).
I'll try to make the question more general to all Obj-c/Swift bridging problems:

There's a code snippet for the AppDelegate.Swift file. However, my AppDelegate is in Objective-C. I've put it into a function (called awsConfig) within a Swift file, referenced the file in the Bridging-Header.h and called the function in the Swift file from my AppDelegate.m:

```
// AppDelegate.m
#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    appsyncer *syncClass = [appsyncer new];
    [syncClass awsConfig];

    return YES;
}
```

And here's the snippet within the Swift file.

```
// SwiftAppDelegateExtension.Swift 
var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?

    do {
        // You can choose the directory in which AppSync stores its persistent cache databases
        let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()

        // AppSync configuration & client initialization
        let appSyncServiceConfig = try AWSAppSyncServiceConfig()
        let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: appSyncServiceConfig,
                                                              cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration)
        appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)

    } catch {
        print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
    }
```

When I want to use it in another Swift file, like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appSyncClient = appDelegate.appSyncClient
```

I get the error:

(!) Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'appSyncClient'

Why doesn't this work? And what would be a better way to tackle this problem if my workaround is too ugly?

Comment: Why not just translate the Swift code into Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

this might be because of the version you currently are working with since this issue can relate to the problem of the versions you are using. So try to use a different version first since this happened to me once and i just used a old version since there are slight changes to the compiler so if you can try different versions and then let me know and make sure to make a report of the versions you tried that failed.

Comment: I suppose you mean Swift- version? If so, I'm using Swift 4.2 . Will need to update my OS and xcode first to upgrade to swift 5. Will get back to you later

Comment: Hi have you updated the swift yet? and if you have does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be a slight error: Turns out I put appDelegate.h instead of appDelegate.m in my bridging-header file. After changing that it works. Probably translating the Swift code to objective C would've been a better option, but this is easier if you're not as skilled in both languages like I am.